# Infinite loop of prerendered 3d graphic

Tags: 2d, 3d, level-design

I have a game where I want a never ending pathway for the character to walk along. So in my 3d modeling tool I created a path like this:

[image: 2d screenshot of 3d model]

now I want to loop that model over and over in my prerendered 2d game for the character to walk on (most of the other game elements are in 2d). The problem is that simply overlaying one image on top of another results in the tiles facing opposite directions. Here's another picture I slapped together so you'll get the idea. In the final game the outer border of the pathway won't separate the two paths.
[image: the tile pattern looks unnatural]

as you can see, the tile pattern looks unnatural, like one pathway segment is a mirror of the other. How can I change the lens/render the model differently so that it can become a seamlessly looping 2d texture?? Can it be done using only the camera view, without a "quadrilateral reshape" or falsely stretching the back end of the platform in my 3d modeler?

Comment: This is not a forum. Please read the guide: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I see. Looks similar to Stack Overflow. The question still applies, however...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a multitude of 3D projections out there with different properties and any 3D modelling tool worth its salt ought to be able to configure the cameras to achieve those looks.

A perspective projection like the one you have used have diminishing widths and heights as you go further away, which will result in the trapezoid shape that you illustrate.

You may be better served by a projection with different properties. An oblique projection (by 3D game developers often called orthographic) does not have the foreshortening you demonstrate and will as such end up with more tileable edges. The look where lines remain parallel may not be one that fits your intended artstyle, of course.

Comment: Thanks! As per what was suggested, I had my camera set to "Perspective" instead of "Orthographic". Setting it the other way around solved my problem.